# Does yaml pipeline not persist environment variables from task to task

Tags: terraform, azure-pipelines

I am working with a terraform script and as I was used to, created one task for authentication and the net one to do my terraform work.
However after spending good hours struggling and debugging I realized that yaml pipeline did not persist the env variables ARM_* that I had set in the first task, neither did

```
az login --service-principal
```

had transferred the authentication to the next task.
I have had to move the authentication to the same task as the terraform script.
This seems to be quite counter intuitive. SO I am posting to see if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Is not the agent supposed to retain environments set in it to the next task?

Comment: In my test, the environment set will be retained in the next task.

Comment: Not get your latest information, would you please share your pipeline definition for further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I tested it through three powershell tasks and everything worked well.

Set variables in the first task:

[image]

Run `az login` in the second task:

[image]

Run az command in the third task:

[image]

The result of running:

[image]

In my test, the environment set will be retained in the next task. You can share your pipeline definition for further investigation.